# VS built dll without debug info. even set to include debug info

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll, pdb-files

same [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net/issues/78) here.

the solution of
https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net
did generate two files

`WebSocket4Net.dll
WebSocket4Net.pdb`

but WebSocket4Net.dll didn't contain Debug Table.[checked with PE viewer].thus no pdb file location info is contained. thus vs debugger refuse to load the pdb. even manually.

The catch is;

- the project is set to debug.
- optimize is off.
- output debug info is set to full.

Is there anything else need to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I tricked myself.
I copied the dll and pdb to my project's output dir.
but every time the my project build. it would be overwritten by project's dll. thus I would see a dll without debug info.
Hope this would help someone. There's no other config needed. check the simplest assumptions that taken for granted.

Comment: @ c19, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who meet the same issue. Thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT ok. I have to wait 24 hours before mark as solved.that's a bit inconvenient, isn't it.